# скажите неучу, почему addEventListener не меняет переменную add вне функции, и как поступать в таком случае если мне нужна измененная переменная?

Tags: javascript

```
let add = false

document.addEventListener('keypress',function(e)
{
  if(e.keyCode == 13)
  {
    add = true
  }
})

console.log(add)
```

Comment: Запустил этот код у себя — всё отлично меняется

Comment: СНАРУЖИ функции add не меняется, внутри да. Хотя обчная функция меняет. Код то сам рабочий. Наверное  с замыкание по другому работает

Comment: Смотри ответ дубликат. А в целом, тебе не нужно это значение снаружи. От слова совсем. Ты всё равно это значение будешь где-то ещё использовать, в какой-нибудь другой функции, которая будет вызываться после отработки текущего события (в качестве колбэка), а, значит, в том месте ты будешь оперировать переменной `add`. А она в функции была изменена...

Comment: можешь вывод сделать из вот этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476674/191482   .. там async/await , но смысл тот же

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Он просто делает выводы исходя из того что выводится в консоль после строки с событием, но он не думает что этот вывод строки срабатывает раньше чем событие, естественно он там ещё не изменился.

Comment: @Elmir Мне не надо это объяснять. Я это вполне понимаю, поэтому дал ссылки на ответы с асинхронностью

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Полегче дядька, я тебе не объясняю как работает этот код

Comment: @Elmir говоря о том, что "думает что этот вывод строки срабатывает раньше чем событие, естественно он там ещё не изменился"  ты по сути и рассказываешь о том, как код работает. Ещё раз: я дал дубликаты не потому что в голову взбрело ткнуть куда попало, а потому, что я вполне знаю что за проблема у человека, мне это пояснять не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код работает, почему вы решили что нет? По вашему выводу в консоль `console.log(add)`? Добавьте вывод в консоль в событие addEventListener, чтобы убедиться

```
let add = false

document.addEventListener('keypress',function(e)
{
  if(e.keyCode == 13)
  {
    add = true
  }
    console.log(add)
})

console.log(add)
```

Так же убедитесь, что указали верный keyCode, 13 - это enter

Comment: Меняет внутри функции но не снаружи. Мне нужна  измененная переменная c наружи функции.

Comment: @ЮсупАдилханов что по вашему первым срабатывает, console.log(add) или addEventListener ? Посмотрите на код, и подумайте над этим.

Comment: А еще.. Не используйте `keyCode`, оно [устарело](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)